# How does a frontend know the currency of which an nft is for sale

Tags: erc-20, erc-721

so in my frontend I've got this - price is fetched by watching events on my marketplace contract... However I assume msgValue will render the price in eth... So my question is in the event that my nft was listed in weth - how would I register this with my front end (what would I replace msgValue with). I assume on the backend each currency would require its own function and this would be how the contract would keep track of what is listed in what currency... Would appreciate any help

```
    const { runContractFunction: buyItem } = useWeb3Contract({
  abi: nftMarketplaceAbi,
  contractAddress: marketplaceAddress,
  functionName: "buyItem",
  msgValue: price,
  params: {
      nftAddress: nftAddress,
      tokenId: token_id,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Chainlink datafeed (https://docs.chain.link/docs/consuming-data-feeds/) that returns the price of ETH in USD.

There are no datafeeds in emulators (e.g. Ganache or the Remix IDE built-in network), so you can test this snippet on your local fork of the Ethereum mainnet.

```
pragma solidity 0.8;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract MyContract {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed;
    // 18 decimals
    uint256 requiredPriceInUsd = 1000 * 1e18;

    constructor() {
        // https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419#code
        // Chainlink ETH/USD Price Feed for Ethereum Mainnet
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419);
    }

    // returns amount of wei
    function getRequiredPriceInWei() public view returns (uint256) {
        (,int answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();

        // returned price is 8 decimals, convert to 18 decimals
        uint256 ethUsdPrice = uint256(answer) * 1e10;

        // 36 decimals / 18 decimals = 18 decimals
        return (requiredPriceInUsd * 1e18) / ethUsdPrice;
    }
}
```

Output from test:

answer is 122884000000 (1228 USD and 8 decimals)
returned value from getRequiredPriceInWei() is 813775593242407473 (of wei, that's ~0.8 ETH for 1,000 USD)